# Type with multiple purposes

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am not even completely sure this is possible, but here we go:

I have a function, which will take a configuration object as it's parameter. The object has two properties and the values they point at should exist as keys in another object (let's call it *data object*). The configuration object's job is to provide the main function with instructions on which props to read when from the data object.

**The configuration object** looks like this;

```
const conf = {
    rootPropName: 'root',
    relationPropName: 'children',
}
```

**Data object**, is a flat object but can created nested structures due to the `relationPropName` (in the configuration, in this case `children`)

```
type ValidKeyTypes = string | number | symbol;

type Input = {
    [key in ValidKeyTypes]: {
        name: string,
        children: (keyof Dummy)[]
    }
}

const data: Input = {
    abc: {
        name: 'ABC',
        children: []
    },
    def: {
        name: 'DEF',
        children: ['ghi']
    },
    ghi: {
        name: 'GHI',
        children: []
    },
    root: {
        name: 'ROOT',
        children: ['abc', 'def']
    }
}
```

**Main function**

```
type Config<T> = {
    rootPropName: keyof T; // a key in the main data object
    relationPropName: keyof T[keyof T]; // a key in an object in the main data object
}

const iterateFlatObject = <T extends object>(config: Config<T>, data: T) => { ... }
```

**Using main function**

```
iterateFlatObject<Input>(config, data);
```

This results in:

> const conf: {
> rootPropName: string;
> relationPropName: string; }
>
> Argument of type '{ rootPropName: string; relationPropName: string; }'
> is not assignable to parameter of type 'Config'.   Types of
> property 'relationPropName' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"children" | "name"'.

So, my question is:
How can I create a dynamic configuration type that can be used

- to describe the properties that my function should target
- as well as giving support and autocompletion that the properties actually do
  exist in the provided data object?

Any suggestions are welcome. Please let me know in case something is unclear.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, but failed. Did I missunderstand anything? See this stackblitz, no error here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-adlusd?file=index.ts

Comment: Hm, that's very odd! It doesn't seem to autocomplete anything however, if I add these lines in the function body: ```const { relationPropName, rootPropName } = config;

  const root = data[rootPropName];
  const rootItems = root[relationPropName];```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the `config` argument is `Config<Input>`. Expanded:

```
{
    rootPropName: ValidKeyTypes;
    relationPropName: "name" | "children";
}
```

The inferred type of `conf` however is:

```
{
    rootPropName: string;
    relationPropName: string;
}
```

The latter cannot be assigned to the former, as it is more general, which is what the error is complaining about.

**What you can do instead** is to define `conf` with an additional `as const`, which tells the compiler to infer the narrowest or most specific type it can. (More details [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)). Like so:

```
const conf = {
    rootPropName: 'root',
    relationPropName: 'children',
} as const
```

The inferred type of `conf` then becomes:

```
{
    readonly rootPropName: "root";
    readonly relationPropName: "children";
}
```

Which now *can* be assigned to `Config<Input>` and the error goes away.

([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMDSEQBVwQM5QC8UewATkgHYDmUAPlJQK4C2ARhGfSSOwPYIA3AChhoSFACSlME2BEoAb2FRVUANoBrTFCqxEqDNlx4AugC4lKtTcpwWES6Qo0ANNZuqAxgAskCFDIISidyKmp1Uw8oAF9hOOEvPkpSKBQ4YDhLaVl5YmUbODYvSwLPVTsHSwByAEEAIQBhavdy7z8AoJCNKJsY1rUUCAAzUujbe0coaoARAFEAMRbxtV9-QODLdWrqP2retX7o3aQxtsZJmoBxAAlJZfO1zs2e6KObMj4+YDO2yqnqgAlADywKwDzaTw23W2RS8LWmQ2G+ze8VE4mgjWSwyQ1AAPFgAHwKMqqT7fAAKnzAADlLlBtCA+MMoFhBFAAPQcqBwBk6PTAHzQFhwPTpTJQPhsABWEC8wGiQQQGSQySpfFp9MZzNZWkwOqwpnZXJ5fJAukoPMtUtl8otUEFwtFlvFvJtcoVCSSKXkSGAnAyEAWyuAwJlHoUBKgEAAHv7KCgCO75YSABTenHUSxYyiZgmE1xpDJZVkASiIxOUaMSyVSGYAjCTFV9gOrNVVpuTgBCyRAQ6rKG26R3qlCussvbX5BmAExNj4tof06pdntQJUqtXU4cAsfBCc8gje0iiP0B-3BjJh23APE5ORphuF12l4RnsiBy+h8Pyu8yB-ptiM7PsWr7orgUAABoKDmeb3sAhJiBBsGNsQGI6g2SESLBc5obgGFAcIQA))